# use functions inside of defaultscope in sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize for a project with a single db for multiple applications. I need to query MSSQL database for each request based on the application_id I receive in the request. (on Nodejs)

Calling a function inside of scope in Sequelize model definition requires specifying the name of the scope for each query which is not desired.

I think if I could use functions inside of defaultscope to make it work (without manually overriding it again and again) . Or if there's any other way to accomplish this (better without rewriting Sequelize functions). Thank you!